# How to find the gradient of my graph python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, graph

How do I find the gradient of my graph, I used data from an external file of an experiment I did. I have tried various different things, I think the issue has come from when I took the data from the external file but I am unsure can someone please help?

The data is for x is 26408, 28956 and 31508 and the data for the y is 4.97, 0.09 and 0

```
import matpoltlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
f = open("Large C 100ohms","r")
lines = f.readlines()[1:]
x = [line.split()[0] for line in lines]
y = [line.split()[1] for line in lines]
x_1 = np.array(x)
#print(x_1)
y_1 = np.array(y)
#print(y_1)
plt.plot(x, y,'bo', linestyle='-')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.xlabel('Time(ms)')
plt.ylabel('Voltage(V)')
plt.title('100 ohms')
#gradient
plt.show()
f.close()
```

Comment: As in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65380791/8881141), you describe a problem that may or may not be related to the way you read in your data but you don't provide a sample file that reflects your input data structure. Please read again [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so you can get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tensorflow:

```
x=[26408,28956]
y=[4.97, 0.09 ]
!pip install tensorflow
import tensorflow as tf 
model=tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1,input_shape=[1])])
model.compile(optimizer="sgd",loss="mean_squared_error")
model.fit(x,y,epochs=3)
print(model.predict([31508]))
```

Output of the prediction=[[-6.44407e+25]] (Which is pretty close to 0)
Also, let me know if you don't wanna use embedded models like this.I mean if you just wanna do it by pure math.